# Android Emulator crashed with opengl error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have android SDK tools: 25.2.2 and SDK platform tools: 25, build tools: 25.

When I tried to launch emulator using AVD manager or Android Studio, it crashed with in few seconds (1-4 seconds) without showing emulator window. Crashed info image attached:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgO9r.png)

Error is something related to OpenGL as mentioned in attached image, but I am not using any OpenGL code, I am just starting fresh emulator.

I tried launching emulator with enabling "Use Host GPU" or disabling also. But same result in both case.

Emulator was working fine few days ago, but I don't know what happens now.

I am running windows 10 pro (32 bit).

Please help.

Comment: *Error is something related to OpenGL,..but I am not using any OpenGL code*  but it says that it has problem with OpenGL drivers on your PC not emulator ... *I am running windows 10 pro **(32 bit).*** ... well recommended 8 GB RAM can not run properly on win32 ... *Emulator was working fine few days ago* restore the system to this point ... it's hard to guess what did you do with your PC since this time

Comment: @Selvin okay. I have no backup so far, I will re-install windows again.

Comment: Prolly you had installed new drivers for graphic card..

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, you are right. Windows updated the graphics driver in background (and may be I missed the notification also). But now I rolled back it to previous version and now at it works fine.

Comment: @Selvin One more thing, if you help me here: actually I was trying to create Android 7.0 emulator with Google API, but when I starts the emulator, then it just show the black screen no booting etc.. Emulator without google api works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, and so far I found out that it may be dependent on the OpenGL version. Some scarce source pointed out at ver. 2+ as min requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Emulator is getting crach before appears in windows..
This is due to following reasons:

1. Check with ur system graphics and also RAM and ROM of the System/laptop.
2. Check with ur sdk path (wheather it is correct or not)
3. did u instaled HAXM in your system?? if not, install - before install change virtualization settings in BIOS

Thanks,

Comment: My PC processor not supporting virtualization feature, that's why I have not installed the HAXM.

Comment: No, every windows must support..this is basic things.., Try to do following Steps...  Step1:  Restart your system and thn press fn+F3/fn+f2 then u will move to BOIS setting. STEP2: then find Virtualization setting  and enable it... then try to install HAXM... Thanks,

Comment: As I know virtualization is supported by processors not windows. BTW I will try your steps and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Yes it's BIOS, try it

Comment: I tried your steps to enable virtualization, but I can't find any setting related to virtualization. I tried following tool: https://www.piriform.com/speccy and it tells me my computer not supported virtualization.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Virtualization enabled, memory allocation etc.  for me.  I now have Windows 10 with 32GB ram and allocated 12GB for HAXM but I keep getting these crashes in different scenarios.  Sometimes when I load the app, sometime when the emulator starts, and other time when I hit the Apply Changes lightening icon...

Comment: These are my errors in the Event log when the emulator crashes.  Emulator: glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x506 internal 0x1906 format 0x1906 type 0x1401

Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: @PrinceH, please go through link- https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html

Comment: @Vincy , Can you please explain in deep.

Comment: @kgsharathkumar what do you mean by "explain in deep" ?  what other information you need from me?  I have explained everything I could...